# Expires option for cookie not working

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

From client side to handle the cookies, I am using the plugin jQuery cookie

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie("language","java",{expires:365});
```

but when I close and open the browser again, there is no cookie with the name, language.

When I verify the Resources section of the developer tool where for this cookie at the time creation expires option contains the value "session", I am not getting why it is taking the the values as Session, even though I assign the value as 365 days.

Comment: `ecpires:365` Really??? Is that just a typo?!

Comment: updated , sorry for the typo mistake

Comment: "session" session cookies are not controlled by javascript.

Comment: but these are created by me on the client side , using that jquery plugin , these are not something created by the application from server side and stored on the client side . Even though i created the cookies and set the value as some number , it is not taking the that values it is taking the default value which is session

Comment: found that this issue with browser , i am running the flows on "Maxthon" , but maxthon will not understand the property expires of cookies , so when i tested the same flow on the chrome , it able to capture the expires values properly and in the Resources tab of developers tools also able to see that value .


thanks everyone , for the helps provided

Answer (score 0):

Try With This

Create session cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```